# Raspbian Stretch multiple wifi networks with different static ip, routers, dns

Tags: raspbian-stretch, dhcp, static-ip

I've two wifi networks, home and work with different static ip, routers, dns. In `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` I can only configure one of them.

I've heard of dhcpd hooks and found this [link](http://www.linuxcircle.com/2016/09/15/raspberry-pi-3-connecting-and-setting-static-ip-addresses-on-multiple-networks/). But I'm pretty sure that this can be simplified by just setting `$new_ip_address`, `$new_routers` and `$new_domain_name_servers` in some hook file.

Ideally what I would need is a different `/etc/dhcpd-"$ssid".conf` per `ssid`

Comment: Your question is internally inconsistent.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: You don't seem to know what OS; your link is about multiple interfaces, but you seem to want to use multiple networks - not to mention you haven't said what Pi. Why do you want to set static IP anyway?

Comment: Ooops, my fault, I've corrected it (/etc/dhcpd-"$ssid".conf). Mine is RPi 3B+ Raspbian Stretch. I'm obliged to use static IP (headless setup). The question is: how do I configure different static IP, routers and domain_name_servers depending on the ssid Rpi connects to? See my answer

Answer (score 1):

How about arping? No need to use hooks. in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
arping 192.168.1.1
arping 10.0.30.1

# home    
profile 192.168.1.1
static ip_address=192.168.1.101/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# work
profile 10.0.30.1
static ip_address=10.0.30.199/24
static routers=10.0.30.1
static domain_name_servers=10.0.2.6
```

Best solution I've found so far

Comment: IIRC You can use 'ssid' instead of 'profile' in dhcpcd.conf. So try `ssid ssidname` followed by the static lines. Have not used it myself, so cannot confirm if it works or not

Comment: @Dirk At home it works. I'll try at work and confirm it. Thanks

Comment: @Dirk Nope. Doesn't work. I checked more throroughly and `ssid` is ignored completely. It always selects the last `static ip_address` disregarding `ssid` section

Answer (score 0):

See **Host Specific Configuration** as described in [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

It is not possible to base this on router SSID but you can set as many networks as you like, based on router `MAC` or IP address.

See `man dhcpcd.conf` although the example is brief and sketchy.